# Is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find a problem for over an hour. I got an error:

```
Error: Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Does anyone know why SimpleController is undefined? Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
                {{ customer.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Kentucky' },
                { name: 'Mister X', :city: 'SF' }
            ];
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your array.  Delete this colon and it'll work

```
$scope.customers = [
            { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Kentucky' },
            { name: 'Mister X', **:** city: 'SF' }
        ];
```

Comment: dangit you beat me to it

Comment: oh man! This habit to put colon before var names came from Rails :) Thanks, it works!! :)

Comment: @Lucas yeah symbols don't translate well to other languages. I also like to use `?` in my functions but no other languages like that either

Comment: yeah, sorry, the system doesn't let me do this earlier

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `:` in front of `:city:`.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/aQHpb/